# Instagram Developer Key Registration Not Available

Tags: instagram-api

I tried to apply the Instagram developer client but realize it's not available.

In the [registration page](https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/register/), 
There should be a Captcha before submitting the application. But it doesn't exist so I always get the error saying "Submission error: please fill out all required fields" while trying to submit.

Does Instagram stop providing new client key?

This screenshot shows that the Captcha is not loaded.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use chrome extension Disable Content-Security-Policy. Captcha is not appearing because of cross domain issue (Instagram need to fix this it is bug on there end).